# Install drupal-project w/ composer failing

Tags: installation, composer

I am trying to install Drupal 8 on Windows using composer and drupal-project.  It is failing on the first package install; cweagans.  I have rebooted the box and checked all the permissions.  Composer is creating the drupal-project folder and I see D:\Websites\drupal-project\vendor\cweagans\ is there.  I have attached a screen shot of the command window with the command and error messages. Does anyone know of a work-around or another method to install drupal with composer?

[image: command window w/ error messages]

Comment: I know it is not recommended, but can you run the same command again with an elevated CMD, i.e. Run as administrator?

Comment: Thanks Ismail. I just tried that but I am getting the same errors.